# MarkerClickListener works as a Button

Tags: android, google-maps, quickaction

I need some help please.

I'm developing a project that uses the GoogleMaps API V2 and it's working fine. My problem is that I need to make the Markers on the screen execute as a BUTTON when clicked. I have a external method to call and it receive a object View as paramter.

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

                    QuickAction.show(null);
                    return false;
                }


            });
```

The Method QuickAction.show needs a View object as Paramter. How can I make it from a marker click?

Thank you.

Comment: "I need to make the Markers on the screen execute as a BUTTON when clicked" -- why do you think that you need this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I need somenthing like this:

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    mQuickAction.show(v);
   }
  });

So I think that if a could make a Listener as Button for the google maps marker, I can get the view object to send my method.

Comment: "I need somenthing like this" -- why do you think you need that? Fix whatever `mQuickAction` is so that it does not need a `View`.